# How do I reserve a packet field?

Tags: java, networking

In java I have put one byte like this. How do I reserve next 3 bytes? I heard that it's better to pack data in multiples of 4 bytes

```
final byte PACKET_TYPE = 3;
bBuffer.put(PACKET_TYPE);
```

Also, if I want to fix a string data field as 48 bytes then how do I handle if string data is less than 48 bytes? I don't want to add the size of string...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, padding:

```
final byte PACKET_TYPE = 3;
final byte PAD_BYTE = 0;
bBuffer.put(PACKET_TYPE);
bBuffer.put(PAD_BYTE);
bBuffer.put(PAD_BYTE);
bBuffer.put(PAD_BYTE);
```

For a fixed-width string field, you could pad with null bytes (a byte of 0), assuming, of course, that the string itself will never contain such bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm going to write an int in that spot, I just mark the buffer, write an int (any old int, doesn't matter), and then when I'm done, go back to the mark and actually write it again with the correct value.